# Certificate decoding error in adobe air

Tags: php, html, air, adobe

I tried a lot googled a lot but no answer.
I created an application in adobe air and now wants to package it.
I am getting error while creating self signed certificate using following command-
This is a format:

```
adt -certificate -cn name [-ou org_unit][-o org_name][-c country] key_type pfx_file password
```

I tried with this examples...

1. `adt -certificate -cn Selfsigned -ou OE -o "Example, co" 1024-RSA SigningCert.p12 39#wnetx3tl`
2. `adt -certificate -cn ADigitalID 1024-RSA SigningCert.p12 39#wnetx3tl`

both returns "certificate decoding error"

Does anybody have solution for that problem???

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error, which I overcame, on a hunch, by switching up to a 2048-RSA keytype.

```
adt -certificate -cn HelloWorld 2048-RSA certficate.pfx password
```